# Select * in Relational Algebra

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

Please explain how to express this SQL statement in relational algebra

```
select * from Books
```

When I search I could find a lot of examples with where clause, I just need to verify that it is  `σ Books` or the answer is something else.

Comment: ` σ Books` is not a valid expression. Why are you suspecting/guessing that it is? Let alone that it expresses what you want? (And what  `σ` call does? And what unnested call for each other operator?) (Rhetorical.)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's

```
Books
```

Relational algebra operators take relation values (among other values) as input and return them as output. Typically a relational algebra query language is or includes expressions that are nested calls to operators. (Don't confuse values & operators with expressions that denote values, via the names of operators & values.) The nesting has to end at leaf expressions denoting relation values. They can be literals describing relations in terms of their parts. Or they can be names of given relation constants or variables. `Books` is such a name. So a query expression returning its value is the expression `Books`. If that wasn't a valid expression for a relation value then you couldn't use it as an argument in a call to an operator in a query expression.